# Whitespace in arithmetic expressions in C

Tags: c

When I write

```
int c = (3+2)*2/5;
```

My programming tool rewrites this as

```
int c = (3 + 2) * 2 / 5;
```

I got some questions.

Is it only accepted by compiler to space between number and operator?
Typing space between number and operator myself is better than depending on tool's automatic help?

Comment: *Whitespace* is irrelevant to a C compiler (`(3+2)*2/5` and .`(3 + 2) * 2 / 5` are equivalent) Your IDE may enforce display syntax rules -- but it has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: *"Is it only accepted by compiler to space between number and operator?"* No, the compiler doesn't care. *"Typing space between number and operator myself is better than depending on tool's automatic help?"* No, it doesn't matter. Type whatever is easier for you to type, and let the tool fix it if necessary.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: White space is not irrelevant to a C compiler. It is not needed in the example shown in the question, but the C standard specifies, both directly and indirectly, several places where it is needed and/or relevant. For example, if we write `0x1e+4` to add the hex constant `0x1e` and `4`, it will not compile.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- yes, of course you are correct. *Whitespace* is needed in your code, but in the example above it is irrelevant. Point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whitespace between tokens is unneeded in general, and completely irrelevant in your scenario.

Exception #1: Whitespace is sometimes needed to denote the end of a token. For example, `int foo(int)` can't be written `intfoo(int)`, and `a+++b` is equivalent to `a++ + b` rather than `a + ++b`.

Exception #2: Line feeds are sometimes significant. For example, it marks the end of a `//` command and of a `#` directive.